# super(new Something(...)) is this construct wrong?

Tags: java

I am looking at some java code where the constructor of a class looks like this:

```
public class X extends ... {
    X(String s) {
       super(new Y(s)); 
    }
}
```

is that always wrong ? 
in other words is it creating an object in the constructor to pass it to 'super' always wrong ? if so why ?

EDIT: 
Why do I think it might be wrong ?

when creating a class X the first thing the jvm does is to call super on its super class. 
(that's done even if 'super()' is implied)
you can only do a limited amount of operations such as `super(new Y(s));` 
maybe a call to super with the ternary operator `super( s != null ? new Y(s) : new Y() )`
but you would not be able to put any more logic because super must be called first !!!
That's why I think it's wrong

Comment: Why do you think it would always be wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that (assuming there's a matching constructor in the superclass).

Comment: @T.J Crowder because it creates an object to pass to the super class. That's wrong. For example why not change it so that the user passes Y in the constructor.

Comment: @Ted Hopp It works it compiles ... but it smells that's my point... but I just fail to understand in which way

Comment: @Zo72: No, it's not "wrong". It's perfectly normal.

Comment: Smells ok to me...  would you also think it smells if X had an overloaded constructor which takes a Y?  Instead of it being on the superclass?

Comment: Just do not end up adding circular Instantiation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will tell you why it smells wrong: because it works only if you can create Y by passing in input s. you have to do everything inside the super statement because that should be called first thing. You would not be able to do something like an if statement to decide what to create or how to create it before calling super

Comment: @Zo72: So? It doesn't matter. (And that's not the question you asked, you asked if it was *always wrong* to create an object in the constructor to pass it to `super`.) In the worst case, if you had to do something really complicated, you might need to give yourself a worker static function to call (which returns the `Y` to pass to `super`), but that doesn't make it always wrong, or indeed smelly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I hear you but I am not convinced. I think it's always wrong and any such code should be refactored like this. Remove constructor which receives a string. Create constructor which receives Y. again my gut feeling maybe you are right...

Comment: @Zo72: All due respect, this is starting to feel like [*"...a rant disguised as a question"*](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and/or a question intended to create a discussion (which is not what SO is for). That logic is limited to a very specific example, which doesn't fit the question of "is it always wrong to create an object to pass to `super`".

Comment: @TJCrowder: this was not a rant at all. I was asking a honest question. I am still not sure about it but I guess your answer was the most clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not always wrong. It's perfectly valid for a subclass to lock in something that the superclass allows you to specify in the constructor.

---

Re your edit:

> ...but you would not be able to put more logic because calling `super`...

That's true, and it's a limitation (an intentional one, I suspect) of the Java programming language, but that doesn't make it *always wrong* to create an object to pass to `super`.

And you can get around that limitation if you want, by defining a static function that returns what you need to pass to `super` and calling it:

```
super(makeTheThingYouNeed());
```

At *that* point, I would definitely double-check that this was really my best course of action before using it. But just creating an object specifically to pass it into `super`? Not a problem at all.

Comment: It's invalid in case Y is an inner-class of X.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *Always* wrong, but as usual there should be a measure to prevent abuses.

In this case it seems as if the new `Y` object was a wrapper of the `s` String or, it was some kind of object required by the superclass of `X`. You're just providing the initialization values of the superclass, and adapting them when needed.

The `Y` object can be created in `X`'s constructor or provided as a parameter directly (with `X`'s constructor receiving an `Y` instead of a `String`). For example, the creation of `Y` is ok if it is a class that you don't have access to from the object that creates `X`.

As you can see, it's all a matter of the current context you're coding in. That very context determines how *wrong* can a decision turn out to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "always" wrong. It is not even "mostly" wrong or *faux pas*. For that matter it is fairly common for child classes to pass information to `super` that way. BUT one does wonder what the other circumstances might be and most of these have little to do with the practice itself.

Is this a way to get around a more extensive initialization of the class? Then maybe it is a bad idea. Does it make it harder to read/debug the code? Then maybe it should be left out.

I also wonder who told you that it was always wrong and why they said that. Was it a fellow developer? A fellow student? An instructor? Categorically saying that "initialization inside of a constructor is wrong" is not something which I have ever seen, but it is something I can imagine a thinks-he-knows-but-doesn't student or professor saying.

Comment: I have edited my question to try to answer why I think it  is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not always wrong, for example

```
public class A {
  public A(final BigDecimal value) {}
}

public class B extends A {
  public B(final String value) {super(new BigDecimal(value));}
}
```

There could be many reasons for doing this, transformation of variables (as above) or maybe the superclass takes an instance of some `protected` class that only `B` can instantiate.

Few things are *always* wrong but many things are sometimes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong in any language sense. However, perhaps it "smells" (as you put it in a comment) because it seems inconsistent to have a subclass relationship between `X` and its superclass if the constructors take completely different types of arguments.

This is a subjective matter that has more to do with OO design philosophy rather than with coding practice. As code, it's perfectly reasonable for a subclass to restrict the types of data with which an object can be created. In fact, it's quite common to do this.